# Rails SpreeCommerce - Does not detect browser language settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, browser, locale, spree, preference

my SpreeCommerce Shop (2.4, spree_i18n 2.4 ist installed) does not detect the browser language preferences. Just the default language will be displayed.

Language configurations are set on the SpreeCommerce admin page ( Supported Locales and Available Locales).

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some logic to your application to set the `Rails.locale` to one of the locales which you support based upon the request `Accept-Language` passed in.

This functionality isn't supported directly by spree-i18n, but designed to be implemented by your application.